# Why do plants not have fat cells, and store their reserves in vacuoles instead?

Tags: evolution, cell-biology, botany, zoology, terminology

Why don't plants have fat cells, but instead store reserves in vacuoles. And *vice versa*, why do humans feature fat cells instead of depositing storage molecules in vacuoles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**
Parallel evolution can generate similar traits in unrelated organisms based on unrelated structures.

**Background**
First off, the question is based on a few misconceptions:

1. First, you are making an apple-and-pear comparison; **Fat cells are [cells](http://www.nature.com/scitable/topicpage/what-is-a-cell-14023083)** - vacuoles are [**organelles**](http://www.biologyreference.com/Oc-Ph/Organelle.html). Fat cells store fats in liquid droplets, called [**adiposomes**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipid_droplet), which are lipid-rich cellular organelles that regulate the storage and hydrolysis of neutral lipids and are found largely in the adipose tissue. **[Vacuoles](http://bscb.org/learning-resources/softcell-e-learning/vacuole-plants/)** have a variety of functions, namely 1) contribute to the rigidity of the plant through hydrostatic pressure; 2) store nutrient and non-nutrient chemicals and 3) break down complex molecules. The latter two functions are quite reminiscent of the function of lipid droplets in *animalia*.
2. **Plants do not store energy reserves in [fats](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27528697)** like animalia do. Instead, plants store **[starch](http://www.pslc.ws/macrog/kidsmac/starch.htm)**, which is not a hydrophobic lipid, but a hydrophilic glucoside polymer.

Apart from these specifics, the question can be tackled more generally - **unrelated organisms can solve the same 'problems'** (like storage of energy rich compounds) **through** **[parallel evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_evolution)** (wings in bats and birds for example). Why does a bat wing contain fingers and a bird's wing doesn't? Because they developed the ability of flight through different, parallel adaptations.